# Javascript/Jquery Pomodoro Clock: Display issue when clock is running

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I am trying to build a simple Podomoro Clock and I'm having an issue with the increment and decrement controls.I want the user to ONLY control the increment/decrement display when the timer is paused(stopped) but instead what happens is the timer display can be controlled no matter what even if the timer is running or stopped.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container text-center">
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h1>FreeCodeCamp Podomoro</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row intervalContainer text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="break">
      <h3>Break Time</h3> <br />
      <button class="btn btn-danger" id="breakMinus">-</button>
      <div id="breakNum">5</div>
      <button class="btn btn-success" id="breakPlus">+</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="Setpomodoro">
      <h3>Pomodoro Time</h3> <br />
      <button class="btn btn-danger" id="workMinus">-</button>
      <div id="pomodoroNum">25</div>
      <button class="btn btn-success" id="workPlus">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row timerContainer text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h2 id="timerStatus">Work</h2>
      <span id="timer">26</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row start_stop">
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center" id="buttonContainer">
      <button class="btn btn-success" id="startBtn">Start</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger" id="stopBtn">Stop</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**JS**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var pomoTime = $('#pomodoroNum');
  var breakTime = $('#breakNum');
  var status = $('#timerStatus');
  var timerDisplay = $('#timer');
  var startButton = $('#startBtn');
  var stopButton = $('#stopBtn');
  var state = 1; // 1=stopped 2=running
  var pomoVal = 24;
  var breakVal = 4;
  var countDown;

  startButton.click(function() {
    if (state == 1) { // if timer is not running then start timer
      state = 2;
      startTimer(pomoVal);

    };
  });

  stopButton.on("click", function() {
    if (state == 2) {
      pauseTimer();
      state = 1;
    }
  });

  updateDisplay();

  function startTimer(time) {

    var minutes = time;
    var seconds = 60;

    countDown = setInterval(function() {

      seconds--;
      minutes = ("0" + minutes).slice(-2); // double digits conversion if <10
      seconds = ("0" + seconds).slice(-2);

      timerDisplay.html(minutes + ":" + seconds);

      if (seconds == 0) {
        minutes-- // decerement minutes when seconds 0...
        seconds = 60; // ..and reset seconds to 60
      }

      if (minutes < 0) {
        clearInterval(countdown);
      }

    }, 1000);

  };

  function pauseTimer() {

    clearInterval(countDown);
  };


  function updateDisplay() {
    if (status == 2) {
      return false;
    }
    $('#breakMinus').on("click", function() {
      status.html("Break");
      if (breakTime.html() > 1) {
        breakTime.html(parseInt(breakTime.html()) - 1);
      };
      timerDisplay.html(breakTime.html());
    });

    $('#breakPlus').on("click", function() {
      status.html("Break");
      breakTime.html(parseInt(breakTime.html()) + 1); // parseInt to covert string into number so it doesn't concatanate.
      timerDisplay.html(breakTime.html());
    });

    // work minus and plus
    $('#workMinus').on("click", function() {
      status.html("Work");
      if (pomoTime.html() > 1) {
        pomoTime.html(parseInt(pomoTime.html()) - 1);
      };
      timerDisplay.html(pomoTime.html());
    });

    $('#workPlus').on("click", function() {

      status.html("Work");
      pomoTime.html(parseInt(pomoTime.html()) + 1); // parseInt to covert string into number to prevent concatanation.
      timerDisplay.html(pomoTime.html());

    });
  };



});
```

I've tried to return the function updateDisplay() to stop it when status is 2(when timer is running). but it still doesn't work.

example : http://codepen.io/aliz16/pen/OXMwRJ?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the state variable in your control event handlers:

```
  function updateDisplay() {
    /*
      Not Needed
      if (status == 2) {
         return false;
      }
    */
    $('#breakMinus').on("click", function() {
      // Check status here
      if (status == 2) {
         return false;
      }
      status.html("Break");
      if (breakTime.html() > 1) {
        breakTime.html(parseInt(breakTime.html()) - 1);
      };
      timerDisplay.html(breakTime.html());
    });

    $('#breakPlus').on("click", function() {
      // Check status here
      if (status == 2) {
         return false;
      }
      status.html("Break");
      breakTime.html(parseInt(breakTime.html()) + 1); // parseInt to covert string into number so it doesn't concatanate.
      timerDisplay.html(breakTime.html());
    });

    // work minus and plus
    $('#workMinus').on("click", function() {
      // Check status here
      if (status == 2) {
         return false;
      }
      status.html("Work");
      if (pomoTime.html() > 1) {
        pomoTime.html(parseInt(pomoTime.html()) - 1);
      };
      timerDisplay.html(pomoTime.html());
    });

    $('#workPlus').on("click", function() {

       // Check status here
      if (status == 2) {
         return false;
      }
      status.html("Work");
     pomoTime.html(parseInt(pomoTime.html()) + 1); // parseInt to covert string into number to prevent concatanation.
      timerDisplay.html(pomoTime.html());

    });
  };
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem still persists, the function shouldn't be executing at all because of the condition but it still does, I'm so confused?

Comment: You mean to say u are able to increase or decrease the counter controls value even after putting the check in the handlers?